# Add css rule specific to component with multiple classes

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<LI id=treeMenu:2 class="ui-treenode ui-treenode-leaf ui-treenode-unselected" role=treeitem sizset="false" data-nodetype="default" data-rowkey="2" sizcache0014053099738481567="771 85 282">
    <SPAN aria-expanded=false aria-checked=false class="ui-treenode-content ui-tree-selectable" aria-selected=false sizset="false" sizcache0014053099738481567="771 85 282">
        <SPAN class=ui-treenode-leaf-icon></SPAN>
        <DIV class="ui-chkbox ui-widget" sizset="false" sizcache0014053099738481567="771 85 282">
            <DIV class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                <SPAN class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-c"></SPAN>
            </DIV>
        </DIV>
        <SPAN></SPAN>
        <SPAN class="ui-treenode-label ui-corner-all">dfvc</SPAN>
    </SPAN>
</LI>
```

I need to add a CSS rule only to LI components that with "ui-treenode ui-treenode-leaf ui-treenode-unselected" class and Besides applies for this div component that is inside on LI:

```
<DIV class="ui-chkbox ui-widget" sizset="false" sizcache0014053099738481567="771 85 282">
```

I've created the following rule but doesn't work

```
li .ui-treenode-leaf span div .ui-chkbox {
   position: relative !important;
   top: -15px !important; 
}
```

I'm working on IE8 and this is HTML generated from node (node without leaf) of Tree component of "Primefaces" (Tree Component on showcase example)

What is the correct CSS rule?

Comment: Your markup is invalid, spans cannot contain divs.  Invalid markup may have unpredictable results.

Comment: @Arbel from your link: `and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` -.-

Comment: Code HTML is from XHTML page

Comment: @WooCaSh Actually I meant the quotations. But it's for `CDATA` not `ID` and `NAME` tokens. `By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39).` So I'll remove my comment. Thanks.

Comment: Oh right. I didn't notice missing quotas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have is that your rule is looking for a tag with class 'tree-node-leaf' within an `li`.

To indicate that you want to target a tag with a specific class, do not put a space between the tag and class.

`li.tree-node-leaf` targets an `li` with that class.

`li .tree-node-leaf` targets a tag with the class `tree-node-leaf` within an `li`.

The same is done with ID selectors, `li#id` targets an `li` with the ID of `id`.  `li #id` targets an element with ID `id` within an `li`.

As Pavlo has said, you should try to keep your selectors as simple as possible - it greatly increases maintenance and reduces the chances of small mistakes becoming big problems.

Try this:

```
li.ui-treenode-leaf span div.ui-chkbox {
   position: relative !important;
   top: -15px !important; 
}
```

Comment: I need that this CSS rules **only** aplies to **LI** HTML components with this class **"ui-treenode ui-treenode-leaf ui-treenode-unselected"**. I've tried with li.ui-treenode-leaf .ui-treenode-unselected span div.ui-chkbox but doesn't work

Comment: That would just be `li.ui-treenode.ui-treenode-leaf.ui-treenode-unselected`.  You can chain classes, so long as you don't have spaces between them.

Comment: @CesarMiguel: You can accept an answer by clicking the Check Mark beside it, if you feel it answers your question.  It's also nice to upvote helpful answers, even if they don't fully answer your question.  You must have 10 rep to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of hierarchy you want in the CSS selectors. If you already defined meaningful class names, there should be no need to include type selectors. It doesn't matter, if you implement `ui-treenode-leaf`s with a `div` or a `li` element.

`.ui-chkbox` should already be sufficient to add styling information, unless you need different styles in specific contexts. But even then `.ui-treenode-leaf .ui-chkbox` should be all you need.

You also should not use `!important`. When you have the need to use `important`, you should think about your classes and about how specific your (other) selectors are.